# Prove that for all natural $n$, $F_{2n - 1}^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {F_{2n + 1}}$ and $F_{2n + 1}^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {F_{2n - 1}}$.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

> Given $F_m$ be the $m^\text{th}$ number in the Fibonacci sequence. Prove that for all natural $n$, $$ F_{2n - 1}^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {F_{2n + 1}} \text{ and } F_{2n + 1}^2 \equiv -1 \text{ (mod }F_{2n - 1})$$

It is sufficient to prove that

\begin{align}
& F_{2n - 1}^2 + F_{2n + 1}^2 + 1 = 3F_{2n - 1} \cdot F_{2n + 1} \\[8pt]
\impliedby {} & F_{2n}^2 = F_{2n - 1} \cdot F_{2n + 1} - 1
\end{align}

but I don't know how to prove that.

And it would be greatly appreciated if there are any other solutions to this problem.

Comment: did you mean $F_{2n+1}^\color{red}2\equiv...$?

Comment: Perhaps you can try proving by induction.

Comment: Cf. [Cassini's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities)

Comment: Do you take $F_{2n}^2 = F_{2n - 1} \cdot F_{2n + 1} - 1$ as given or do you want to prove that? The implication suggests you already know that one.

Comment: Sure, I would love to see a solution using induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a stronger statement, that $F_{n}^2 = F_{n-2}F_{n+2} + (-1)^n$.

For $n = 1$, $F_1^2= 1= F_{-1}F_{3}+(-1)$.

Assume that for some $n=k$, $F_{k}^2 = F_{k-2}F_{k+2} + (-1)^k$.

For $n=k+1$,

$$\begin{align*}
F_{k+1}^2 - F_{k-1}F_{k+3}
&= (F_{k-1}+F_{k})F_{k+1}-F_{k-1}(F_{k+1}+F_{k+2})\\
&= F_kF_{k+1}-F_{k-1}F_{k+2}\\
&= F_k(F_{k+2}-F_k)-(F_k-F_{k-2})F_{k+2}\\
&= -F_{k}^2+F_{k-2}F_{k+2}\\
&= -(-1)^k\\
F_{k+1}^2&= F_{k-1}F_{k+3} + (-1)^{k+1}
\end{align*}$$

Alternatively, like the matrix proof in [Cassini's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities),

$$\begin{align*}
F_{k+1}^2 - F_{k-1}F_{k+3}
&= \det\pmatrix{F_{k+1}&F_{k+3}\\F_{k-1}&F_{k+1}}\\
&= \det\pmatrix{F_{k+1}&F_{k+2}\\F_{k-1}&F_{k}}\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}\\
&= \det\pmatrix{F_{k}&F_{k+2}\\F_{k-2}&F_{k}}\pmatrix{-1&0\\1&1}\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}\\
&= (F_k^2 - F_{k+2}F_{k-2}) (-1)(1)\\
F_{k+1}^2&= F_{k-1}F_{k+3} + (-1)^{k+1}
\end{align*}$$

So $F_{n}^2 = F_{n-2}F_{n+2} + (-1)^n$ is true by induction.

---

Substituting special cases $2n-1$ and $2n+1$ respectively,

$$\begin{align*}
F_{2n-1}^2 &= F_{2n-3}F_{2n+1} -1 \equiv -1 \pmod{F_{2n+1}}\\
F_{2n+1}^2 &= F_{2n-1}F_{2n+3} -1 \equiv -1 \pmod{F_{2n-1}}\\
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

To prove [Cassini's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities) $F_{2n}^2=F_{2n-1}\cdot F_{2n+1}-1$,

you could use [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) $F_n=\dfrac{\phi^n-\left(\dfrac{-1}{\phi}\right)^n}{\sqrt5},$

where $\phi$ is the golden ratio, which satisfies $\phi-\dfrac1\phi=1$.